# obtener tiempo transcurrido en django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Estoy creando un task en Django en el que necesito sacar todos los pedidos y comprobar la fecha de creación para ver cuanto tiempo ha transcurrido, en caso de que hayan pasado 2 días ejecutar un código y en caso de que hayan pasado 4, ejecutar otro distinto.

ahora mismo mi modelo es así:

```
class Pedido(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=9, editable=False)
    fecha = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    precio_producto = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12,decimal_places=2)
    precio_envio = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6,decimal_places=2)
    nom_producto = models.CharField(max_length = 40)
    talla = models.CharField(max_length = 5)
    marca = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
```

el código que tengo ahora mismo es así:

```
pedidos = Pedido.objects.all()
for p in pedidos:
    tiempo_transcurrido = date.today() - p.fecha
    if tiempo_transcurrido == timedelta(days=2):
        pass
    elif tiempo_transcurrido == timedelta(days=4):
        pass
    elif tiempo_transcurrido == timedelta(days=5):
        pass
```

El servidor me devuelve este error:

> dias = date.today() - p.f_ped
>   TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.date' and 'datetime.datetime'

Comment: Por favor revisa la indentación del código. Es sintácticamente incorrecta. Por otro lado, no veo que la clase `pedido` tenga un campo llamado `f_ped` como el que usas en tu segundo código. Finalmente, no indicas qué problema tienes con tu código actual (da un error? no funciona como querías?)

Comment: si perdona, voy a modificar y completar con el error que obtengo

Comment: Gracias. El segundo fragmento de código aún parece mal indentado ¿No debe estar el `for` a la misma altura que la primera línea?

Comment: Cierto, no me habré dado cuenta, gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que python tiene dos formas de obtener la fecha actual. Una es a través de `datetime.date.today()` y la otra a través de `datetime.datetime.today()`. El primero te devuelve un objeto de tipo `datetime.date`, mientras que el segundo te devuelve un objeto de tipo `datetime.datetime` (que además de la fecha incluye la hora exacta).
Juan
En tu código (segundo fragmento) usas un objeto de tipo `datetime.date`,  mientras que django recupera la fecha de la base de datos como de tipo `datetime.datetime`, y ambos no pueden ser restados, porque el primero no tiene la hora.

Usa en tu código `datetime.datetime.today()` para obtener la fecha actual.

**Actualización**. Según un comentario del usuario, la solución anterior aún da problemas. En este caso se debe a que la fecha-hora almacenadas en la base de datos de Django incluyen la zona horaria (*timezone*), mientras que la que obtenemos con `datetime.datetime.today()` por defecto no lo tiene.

La solución: usar `datetime.datetime.now()` en vez de `today()`, ya que éste permite incorporar información sobre la zona horaria, que voy a suponer que es `utc` (otro problema será lidiar con zonas horarias diferentes).

```
from datetime import timezone
ahora = datetime.datetime.now(timezone.utc)
```

Comment: ahora me devuelve otro error: tiempo_transcurrido = datetime.today() - p.fecha
TypeError: can't subtract offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes

Comment: @FDelgado Actualizada la respuesta

Comment: el método today no acepta argumentos

Comment: @fdelgado perdón, era `now()`, como decía más arriba Corregido

Comment: ahora si me está funcionando, sobre el tema de la zona horaria es que este trabajo es para Colombia y no para España ¿necesitaria cambiar el timezone o tal y como está me valdría? ya es es por curiosidad

Comment: @FDelgado A la hora de restar las fechas, tendrías que usar la misma zona horaria al invocar `now()` que la que está almacenada en la base de datos. Probablemente esté almacenada también en UTC. Puedes verlo si imprimes el valor de `repr(p.fecha)`, pues te mostrará algo como `datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 15, 21, 25, 36, 728901, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)` donde podrás leer la zona horaria que se usó.